# How do I test the presence of the element on the page?

Tags: c#, html, browser

I'm trying to click a link using this line:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")[i].InvokeMember("click");
```

But when the element is not present on the page it gives me the error `Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'`.

I tried testing the element's presence first:

```
if (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a") != null) {...}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

How do I check if the element is present?

Comment: Is it a compile error or a runtime error (an exception)?

Comment: what does this `webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(download_handler);
` line do?

Comment: the line you're asking about deletes the handler once work is done. This way handler will not be added multiple times, causing program to do same thing multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")` yields an *empty* collection.

Your second sample test for `null` but that is something different.

Use the debugger to see `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a").Count`

Answer (score 1):

why not use ...

```
foreach (HtmlElement elem in elemColl) { }
```

and that Kev that line -= removes the event handler

Comment: the GetElelemtsByTageName returns a collection of HtmlElements which is Ienumerable so rather than using a loop you might as well use the for each.

so foreach (HtmlElement ele in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))

Answer (score 0):

Are you *sure* there are any elements in the collection?

When you call

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
```

you get back a collection - it could have 1, 2, 100 or... 0 elements in it.  The collection might be empty.  You could call .Count() on it and see.